# I want to send a Python request to an ASP site but the site show access denied

Tags: python, request

Site url is http://rajresults.nic.in/resbserx18.htm when send data, but when response comes URL changes in ASP. So which URL user need to send request ASP or html?

Request:

```
import requests
# data for get result
>>> para = {'roll_no':'2000000','B1':'Submit'}
# this is url where data is entered and get asp response
>>> url = 'http://rajresults.nic.in/resbserx18.htm'
>>> result = requests.post(url,data=para)
>>> result.text
```

Response

```
'The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a little bit of work, I found it's some issue with the headers.
I did some trial and error, and found that it checks to make sure the `Host` header is set.

To debug this, I just incrementally removed chrome's request headers and found which one this web service was particular about.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Host": "rajresults.nic.in"
}

r = requests.post('http://rajresults.nic.in/resbserx18.asp',
        headers = headers,
        data = {'roll_no': 2000000, 'B1': 'Submit'}
)

print(r.text)
```